# Root site collection context in sub site's SharePoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, jsom

I am creating SharePoint hosted app and installed in sub site, Now my requirement is i want to save some document in style library of root site collection How to achieve this?

When I tried to create context like

```
appWebContext = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
rootContext = new SP.AppContextSite(appWebContext, rootWebUrl);
```

performing some operations on context and while execution console showing error rootContext.load is not a function.

This code isn't working on sub site's app but when I execute code on root site's app then code works perfectly.

Comment: You need to get the client context for the root site and using same client context upload the file to style library